# Retrieve Excel Imbedded Objects by their original file name or file type

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I have an Excel sheet that allows users to click on specific cells and attach/embed files. Is there an API available to retrieve these files by filename or file type? I've tried Apache POI to read PackagePart and get contents there. I've tried POIFS file system. And I've tried Apache TIKA(TikaConfig getDetector()) to get mime type.

They all return the same information: OLEObject1.bin, OLEObject2.bin, OLEObject3.bin, etc or strings that can't be used to differentiate files.

If I was trying to differentiate between PDFs, PPTs, or XLS it's straightforward, however I need to look for specific file types and/or names so I know how to properly process them for further examination.

Is there anyway to get past the generic OLEObject1.bin format?

Comment: Have you tried unpacking the OLE objects to see what's inside them?

Comment: I have searched the objects extensively looking for something useable. Drilling down several layers, using Apache POI or TIKA, has resulted in "/xl/embeddings/oleObject1.bin" or "application/vnd.opemxmlformats...., or simply oleObject1.bin. For example, if the original file name was example.txt or example.wsq, is there a way to retrieve "example" or ".txt" or ".wsq"?

Comment: Try looking inside the ole object (with Tika or POI), do you find your text file embedded in there?